# Trackpad orientation rotation by 90 degrees on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, touchpad

I am using this application called "Inklet". It lets you draw with gestures on your trackpad. It is working fine except that what ever I draw gets rotated by an angle of 90 degrees counter-clockwise.

So for example, if I draw a straight line along Y-axis, it draws a straight line along X-axis and vice versa.

Does anybody know whats going wrong here? Is there a way I can rotate the orientation of trackpad by 90 degrees?

Answer (score 0):

To rotate trackpad (bluetooth one...)
Just open terminal and type:

```
sudo sudo defaults write com.apple.MultitouchSupport ForceAutoOrientation YES

sudo defaults write com.apple.trackpad.orientation TrackpadOrientationMode 1
```

No need to reboot, just disable and enable bluetooth it will work...

Just applied it on 10.10.2

Comment: -1 because this rotates the trackpad 180°, not 90°

Answer (score 0):

This appears not to work anymore on MacOS 10.12 (Sierra). Apparent corroboration from Apple forum: https://discussions.apple.com/message/30704137#message30704137

Answer (score -1):

BetterTouchTool works for 180 degree rotation (not 90), and is supported up through Mojave. The 1st gen Apple trackpad is far more comfortable rotated 180 degrees; the second generation is only a bit better than way, as the slope is less.